# Load csv vs batch importer. Which is faster?

Tags: neo4j

If I want to import a Dataset that has 18M nodes and 150M relationships into neo4j, which import method is going to be faster? I'm using 2.2 version on Windows 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

batch importer will be faster since it does not care about transactions.

Answer (score 0):

BatchInserter is the super fast way to upload the dataset anyway ...but this is only one time import. On the other hand if you use load CSV technique then you can upload your dataset incrementally but marginally slow. Hope this helps.